# Undefined value when press submit button after taking input

Tags: javascript, react-native, cross-platform

I'm new to react development.I got this error `undefined` after press the submit button.I checked the input field and it probably not taking valid input.here I added my code,please check it and give some solution

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {v4} from 'uuid';
import {
Container,
Content,
Form,
Item,
Input,
Label,
Text,
Button,
} from 'native-base';
export default class ContactFrom extends Component {
state = {
id: v4(),
fullName: '',
};
handelChange = e => {
this.setState({
fullName: e.target.value,
});
};
handelSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();

alert(this.props.add­Contact(this.state))­;
};

render() {
return (
<React.Fragment>
<Container>
<Content>
<Form>
<Item floatingLabel>
<Label>Full Name</Label>
<Input
onChange={e => this.handelChange(e)­}
value={this.state.fu­llName}
name="fullName"
/>
</Item>
</Form>
<Container>
<Content>
<Button onPress={e => this.handelSubmit(e)­} primary>
<Text>Submit</Text>
</Button>
</Content>
</Container>
</Content>
</Container>
</React.Fragment>
);}}
```

please review my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing what you are doing wrong is changed text will not be in `e.target.value` change it to `e.nativeEvent.text`

That is change

```
handelChange = e => {
this.setState({
fullName: e.target.value,
});
};
```

to

```
handelChange = e => {
this.setState({
fullName: e.nativeEvent.text,
});
};
```

check it by alert(this.state) in handleChange function.
Hope this helps!